# Delay timer in between record execution

Tags: apex, batch, execute-anonymous

I was wondering if there any batch method that will allow me to add a delay between 2 records. Sy for example I have 100 records. I want to add a delay for execution between record 1 and record 2 and so on and so forth between 100 records?

I tried to do and posted on a different question [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302790/add-a-delay-timer-when-a-batch-class-is-executed-without-scheduler) but it was batch wise, this is single record execution.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Meanwhile I will keep trying to find more.

Thanks!

EDIT: If batch size is one, will the [above](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302790/add-a-delay-timer-when-a-batch-class-is-executed-without-scheduler) solution work? I think so. I will keep trying..

Comment: Why do you want to do that? How much time delay are you looking for, and what are the minimum and maximum allowed delay values?

Comment: 2 minutes of delay between each record. There is a issue on the external system that if a user tries to update more than 1 record within 2 minutes, the account will lock out.

Comment: Are you processing a record and sending the record details to an external service callout? And performing DML on the external system that requires 2 min delay between each DML??

Comment: That right @arut

Comment: Is it important that the call out happens right after those two minutes or would for instance 15 minutes also be acceptable?

Comment: As of now 2 minutes or could be any number. Are you hinting at a scheduler? The code will be run from developer console only, so trying to avoid scheduler as it's a one time batch. Apologise that I didn't mention that in my question and wasn't clear enough.

Comment: I think a scheduled batch job would work. I've once solved something similar with a queuable job that created another one when finished. I then checked if the last job had executed more than a minute ago and if not I simply rescheduled it. On average the jobs would execute in around 45 seconds i think. It's not pretty, and it takes a long time to run if you have a lot of records, but it worked.

Comment: Alternatively, you could consider scripting this from the command line or from a simple lwc component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added the below code in the execute method. I feel this is not right, but this is what is needed and working for me right now. The following code delays the consecutive batches by 9s. I tested with 2 records and was working as expected.

```
Long startTimerTime = DateTime.now().getTime();
Long finishTimerTime = DateTime.now().getTime();

while ((finishTimerTime - startTimerTime ) < 12000) {
//delay for 12 seconds
    finishTimerTime = DateTime.now().getTime();
}
```

Please feel free to correct or comment me on this answers. I'm sure there is a better solution out there.

UPDATE: Tested successfully with 100 records with delay of 5 seconds.